# How to correctly write a raster image (tif) from a value matrix with python

Tags: python, gis, rasterio

I am starting to work with Geographic Information Systems and I need some advice from you. I need to convert tif (raster) into a 3D matrix, for example, the previous matrix in pandas:

```
M = [[1, 1]
     [2, 4]
     [3, 1]]
```

After exploring python packages, I found that I can do that with [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io). I use the following code:

```
new_dataset = rasterio.open('test5.tif', 'w', driver='GTiff', height = arr.shape[0], width = arr.shape[1], count=1, 
    dtype=str(arr.dtype),
    crs='+proj=utm +zone=19 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs',
    transform=transform)
)
new_dataset.write(arr, 1)
new_dataset.close()
```

following this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279953/numpy-array-to-gtiff-using-rasterio-without-source-raster). So, for this tiny input it seems to work fine, yielding the following tif:

[image]

When I try with a real matrix loaded form las/LIDAR, which have the dimensions: (32019, 5), and a head:

```
              x             y        z  Classification  ReturnNumber
0  506535.92650  4.762852e+06  4.98525               1             2
1  506534.48700  4.762853e+06  0.00000               2             1
2  506542.35150  4.762849e+06  0.04950               1             1
3  506544.38850  4.762848e+06  0.00000               2             1
4  506543.54475  4.762848e+06  0.00000               2             1
```

I obtain this:

[image]

however, for this same image, the whitebox tool yields this one

[image]

using this code:

```
import os
import whitebox

wbt = whitebox.WhiteboxTools()
wbt.work_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/data/"

wbt.lidar_idw_interpolation(
    i="input.las",
    output="output.tif",
    parameter="elevation",
    returns="all",
    resolution=1.0,
    weight=1.0,
    radius=2.5
)
```

The output of whitebox tool is the correct one, and comparing both images it seems to be that the first is like negative effect respect the  whitebox's output. There is some thing wrong in my code??

Any advice of how change the color of the pixels (2D) according other density matrix?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show us the `real matrix loaded form las/LIDAR`, please ?

Comment: hi @lenik, I updated my question where I included the first column of the matrix. Thanks!

Comment: how did you get a relatively square image from the matrix of shape  (32019, 5) ? and given 5 columns in the matrix, what of those columns do you expect to see in your image ?

Comment: I used laspy package to load the LIDAR image. I expect to obtain a 2D image (axis x and y).

Comment: to create the matrix I apply the script: for i, row in data.iterrows():
    arr[int(row["x"])-int(min_x)][int(row["y"])-int(min_y)] = int(row["z"])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there are `(x,y)` points you don't have the data for, and these points remain black on your picture. Whitebox, on the other hand, does some kind of interpolation for these missing points.

You may want to find these points and also interpolate the missing `z` value from the existing neighbours. There might be some special interpolation methods for your data, but if I were you, I'd apply gaussian filter a few times again and again, copying the valid data over the filtered data to preserve the known to be good pixels from any changes -- this should fill the black spots with the reasonable approximation.